# Carbon nano Tube

Tags: nanoscience

I am a new to this field and want to know which process (T-CVD or CVD spray pyrolysis) is better for mass production purposs. i have tried more then 50 process on TCVD and started getting good raman analysis result like (Ig/Id=9.25), but bad CNT formation.

Comment: From G/D ratio, I think that you want to make SWCNTs. There are some questions. What are the bad CNT formation, the catalyst, carbon source gases and growth temperature? If you cannot answer the information, it's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make SWCNTs? Yes?
About bad CNTs, do they have bending portion, defects, broken and?

How did you make TEM sample of CNT? SWCNTs are damaged when it's dispersed by the sonication. So to observe the as-grown SWCNTs using TEM, SWCNTs are necessary to be directly put on the microgrid of TEM.

And how much the accelerate voltage of TEM is? Also SWCNTs are damaged by the accelerate voltage more than about 100 keV. After these factors are removed, as-grown CNTs can be observed by TEM and discussed about the formation.

If you have already clarified these factors, it is necessary for the form (crystallinity) of CNTs to consider about the catalysts and the growth condition.

I think that obtaining CNTs with G/D ratio of ~9 using acetylene gas as a carbon source is good result. So I think that high crystallinity CNTs can be obtained by considering above factors.